# Weighted lattice paths

Tags: python, algorithm

for the the algorithm on this link(https://projecteuler.net/problem=638) I wrote the following code, but because it is dealing with large integers and it takes a long time I am looking for ways to make it efficient, could any body please read my code and give some suggestions,

```
def WeightedLatticePaths(k):
sigma = []
for m in range(1,k+1):
    X = pow(10,m)+m
    n = 2*X
    x=0
    y=0

    paths =[]
    for i in range(pow(2,n)):
        if ('{0:0%db}'%n).format(i).count('1')==X:
            paths.append(('{0:0%db}'%n).format(i))

    c = []
    for i in range(len(paths)):
        a = []
        route = paths[i]
        for item in route:
            if item=='0':
                y+=1
            if item=='1':
                x+=1
                a.append(y)
        p = sum(a)
        c.append(pow(m,p))

    C = sum(c)
    sigma.append(C)
return sum(sigma)%(1000000007)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). It will be more efficient but I'm not sure whether it will be efficient enough. By the way, the Python [pow](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#pow) builtin you're using can take third argument - modulus. Use it for modular exponentiation.

The rule of a thumb when solving problems which results are modulated, is to use modulus wherever you can during your calculations. Thus you ensure that number you are using will not be grater than your modulus.